# New type casting in Java 8 or I'm making a mistake?

Tags: java, casting, type-conversion

I see a new form of type casting in some codes related to JavaFX. The strange thing about it is its functionality that works like type casting but I can't find it [under the categories of casting in Java 8 Specifications](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html). This is an example:

```
    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("tabs/tabbedWin.fxml"));
    TabbedWinController twc1 = loader.<TabbedWinController>getController();
    TabbedWinController twc2 = (TabbedWinController) loader.getController();
```

The two last lines seem to do the same job but I wonder what the syntax in front of `twc1` mean? It is completely new to me.

If it is type casting why can't I use the statements like `int i = <Integer> f;` where f is a float variable?

So I'm curious to understand what it is? Since when it has been added to Java? Where I should/can/shouldn't use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the way you specify the generic type to a `static` method. It has been available since generics were released in Java 5.

```
List<String> emptyListOfStrings = Collections.<String> emptyList();
```

In your case both forms work fine because the `getController` method returns an object of the specified generic type.

See [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/methods.html) for a discussion.

Answer (score 1):

It's not related to JavaFX, methods of that form are called **generic methods** and have nothing to do with casting.

So when you write

```
loader.<TabbedWinController>getController();
```

it means that you want `getController()` to return an object of type `TabbedWinController`.

Comment: So, why is <TabbedWinController> inserted where it works also without it, without any syntax error or warning?

Comment: If you call `getController()` without the generic type, this method will simply return an `Object`. If you cast that to `TabbedWinController` like in your second case, the returned Object will be what you want. **EDIT:** I looked into that method and all it does is `return (T)controller;`. So actually the method casts the controller for you, when you call it with the generic type. So the result is the same as when you get the controller as an Object and cast it yourself.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Anyway I selected the other answer as the best because it refered the tutorial page that had explained why it works and without that notation. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/methods.html -- where it says "Generally, this can be left out and the compiler will infer the type that is needed"